# Is there a way to override the browser's default behavior for clicking on hashes?

Tags: javascript, html, hash, default, behavior

When I have the following:

```
<a name='test'></a>
```

...and load it in a browser, I can append `#test` to the URL and the browser will scroll so that the `<a>` is at the top of the page.

**However,** I would like to change this behavior (using JavaScript if possible) so that using the hash *does not* scroll the page - I'd like it to simply do nothing.

Is there a way to do that *without* removing the `<a>` element?

---

**Update:** I need the browser to still send `onhashchange()` events but without scrolling to the `<a>` element. The reason being that I want to override the scrolling while retaining the event notification.

Comment: Why do you have this element if you don't want to jump there?

Comment: @Felix: I don't. I have no control over the page contents... I'm writing a USerScript.

Answer (score 2):

A quick dirty hack, but it's something you can build upon:

```
var curScroll = prevScroll = $(window).scrollTop()

$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
  prevScroll = curScroll
  curScroll = $(this).scrollTop()
}).bind('hashchange', function() {
  $(this).scrollTop(prevScroll)
})
```

I used jQuery here to make it work across browsers and keep the page's onhashchange and onscroll handlers intact. One problem I spotted is that if you click the same hashtag twice it scrolls anyway.

---

**UPD.** I just figured out a better solution:

```
$('a').live('click', function() {
  if (this.href.split('#')[0] == location.href.split('#')[0]) {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop()
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(window).scrollTop(scrollTop)
    }, 0)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can try to be brutal:

```
var i, elems = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].removeAttribute('name');
}
```

It has to be run after the DOM is ready but before it gets rendered so you have to put it in the right place. It won't work for 'id' attributes - only with <a name=...>

Does it do what you want?

Comment: Well... I guess I should have explained the problem a bit more... but I need the browser to still send `onhashchange()` events **but** without scrolling to the `<a>`.

Comment: Well I guess you didn't because it does exactly what you just said in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
$( 'a[href="#"]' ).click( function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A kind-of hacky technique would be to just automatically scroll to the top of the page if there's a hash in the url:

```
if (window.location.hash) {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: And maybe bind this function also to `window.onhashchange`. But the problem is that this will always jump to the top. So it is not doing *nothing*.

Comment: @Felix ooh yeah forgot about that.

Comment: This ought to work, however depending how early userjs gains control (ie: GreaseMonkey vs. Opera).

Answer (score -1):

perhaps you need to use a bit of jquery and string manipulation

```
removeHashPartFromString = function() {
 ...
}

$('a').each(function() {
    this.attr('href') = removeHashPartFromString(this.attr('href'));
});
```

Or find the elements with the hash and remove the name hash attributes from those elements.

Comment: How does this help with the **name** attribute and adding `#name` the URL manually (i.e. not clicking)?

Comment: My understanding of the problem is - anchor tag has #name which makes the browser move to the location of the matching element in the page. And so the solution that I suggested was removing the #name from the anchor tag.